# Representations of Nilpotent Lie Subalgebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Does every nilpotent lie subalgebra of gl(V) is representable by triangular matrices with 0 on the diagonal?

Comment: My apologies for my erroneous earlier answer. Please see Andreas Cap's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for rather simple reasons: Any one-dimensional subspace in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is an Abelian (and hence nilpotent) Lie subalgebra. This can be represented by upper triangular matrices with $0$ on the diagonal if and only if it is spanned by a nilpotent map.

Engel's theorem as mentioned in the comment by @peter_a_g is not a theorem about nipotent Lie subalgebras in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ but about Lie subalgebras consisting of nilpotent endomorphisms of $V$. (It then implies that such a subalgebra is nilpotent, but the converse is not true.)

Comment: I was tempted to leave my original stupid comment (albeit with a retraction) as a warning - but I did not. Thank you for the correction. BTW, unfortunately the at-sign-name in an answer does not seem to warn the designated person (i.e., does not mark 'recent messages' in red). This seems only to happen for comments. One should ask Stack Exchange why, though I bet the question has been asked before.